# constexpr power of 10 in non-recursive way?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++14, template-meta-programming, constexpr, pow

It is very easy to implement `constexpr` power of 10 in recursive way:

```
template<int exp, bool = (exp > 0)>
struct pow10 {
    static constexpr double value = pow10<exp - 1>::value * 10.0;
};

template<>
struct pow10<0, false> {
    static constexpr double value = 1.0;
};

template<int exp>
struct pow10<exp, false> {
    static constexpr double value = pow10<exp + 1>::value / 10.0;
};

template<int exp>
static constexpr double pow10_v = pow10<exp>::value;

static_assert(pow10_v<-3> == 1e-3, "");
static_assert(pow10_v<2> == 1e2, "");
```

Is it possible to make `constexpr` power of 10 in non-recursive way?

FYI, I'm using VS2015 which does not support relaxed-`constexpr` in C++14 well, thus, I cannot use for-loop in `constexpr` function.

Comment: "Computed at compile time" is not the same as "constant expression" or "constexpr". If you want a constant expression, then no (not sure why you would want one either). Most modern compilers will happily compute `pow` at compile time. Note there's no guarantee whatsoever that `pow(10,-3) == 1e-3`, computed at run time or at compile time.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you. I edited the question to make clear.

Comment: Does it have to be a template meta program? How about a macro that uses token pasting to create `1E<power>`?

Comment: Why do you need constexpr, and why do you want a non-recursive solution?

Comment: @Barmar I need template metafunction. @n.m. Well, fundamentally, I just wonder such technique. `constexpr` is required to use it as a metafunction.

Comment: You can use a simple lookup table (an array). About 600 elements will cover all powers of 10 that fit in an IEEE double. No templates, no recursion, just constexpr functions and data. Why do you need a `double` metafunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you compile C++14 but your compiler isn't full compliant with C++14 `constexpr` functions. So you cant make a loop inside a `constexpr` function.

Well... I don't have your compiler so I don't know what, exactly, your compiler doesn't support, so I propose a C++14 solution based over a non-recursive `constexpr` variadic template function that doesn't use a for loop. Well... two functions: one for negative powers and one for non-negative powers.

Hoping VS2015 support it.

The negative function is the following

template

```
constexpr T negPow10 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = std::size_t[];

   T ret { 1 };

   (void)unused { 0U, (ret /= 10, Is)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

The non-negative (for positive or zero powers) is almost equals but use `ret *= 10` instead of `ret /= 10`.

They are called through the following

```
template <typename T, int E, std::size_t N = (E < 0 ? -E : E)>
constexpr T pow10 ()
 { return E < 0
    ? negPow10<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    : posPow10<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }
```

The following is a full compiling example (but observe that, as pointed by n.m., the `static_assert()` over the `double` power isn't reliable)

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr T posPow10 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = std::size_t[];

   T ret { 1 };

   (void)unused { 0U, (ret *= 10, Is)... };

   return ret;
 }

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr T negPow10 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = std::size_t[];

   T ret { 1 };

   (void)unused { 0U, (ret /= 10, Is)... };

   return ret;
 }

template <typename T, int E, std::size_t N = (E < 0 ? -E : E)>
constexpr T pow10 ()
 { return E < 0
    ? negPow10<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    : posPow10<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( pow10<long, 5>() == 1e5, "!" );
   static_assert( pow10<double, -3>() == 1e-3, "!" );
 }
```

To be honest, this solution is (or can be) a little recursive in `std::make_index_sequence`.

Comment: VS 2015 can compile none of these c++14 constructs it seems.

Comment: @n.m. - This is exactly what I was afraid of: if it doesn't support a for loop, is to be expected that the `constexpr` support is at C++11 level.

Comment: Repeatedly multiplying or dividing with/by 10 will lose precision for bigger exponents.